# Quantity wise price searching in Apache SOLR

Tags: search, solr, search-suggestion

Currently I am working on e-commerce website where price can be vary based on quantity.

For e.g

```
Product A
    --------------------------------------- 
    Quantity | 25   | 50   | 70   | 90+   |
    ---------------------------------------
    Price    | 0.76 | 0.79 | 0.65 | 0.60 |
    ---------------------------------------

Product B
    ---------------------------------------
    Quantity | 25   | 40   | 65   | 80+   |
    ---------------------------------------
    Price    | 0.81 | 0.73 | 0.62 | 0.60  |
    ---------------------------------------
```

Please note that quantity break will be different for one and another product.

How I should save into solr so it fulfill following criteria.

- If user search for desired quantity, system should pick price from that quantity range. If User search for 60 then system should show 0.65 for "Product A" and 0.62 for "Product B"
- Also user selects desired quantity and sort by price "lowest to highest"   It should match the price where selected quantity falls. If user search for quantity 60 then "Product B"(0.62) should be first and "Product A"(0.65) should be second.
- If user sort "lowest to highest" without selecting quantity then system show show "Product A" should be first and "Product B" should be second as Product A (0.76) has lowest price than Product B(0.81)